# PC audio stuttering/noise every 2-3 seconds

Tags: windows-10, audio, noise, windows-10-v21h2

I have a Gigabyte B450M-DS3H motherboard which I've been using for a long time now.

Recently, the audio has started to be distorted and stuttered, this is not a constant problem, it occurs every few seconds, probably in response to processor activity.
There's an electric activity sound as if the computer would have been going BSOD every 2-3 seconds.
I've checked on Task Manager and the processor activity reflects the timelines of those sounds.

The audio headphones are connected directly to the motherboard rear audio jacks, but I've also tried the monitors speakers (connected with HDMI) and the problem persists.

Any other things to try out in order to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Since it seems a gradual change, check filter electrolytic caps on mother board and in power supply. Also, check the CPU and GPU temps, e.g., with WHinfo. If a bit high, it could cause throttling. If high, dust thoroughly. Some suggest putting on new thermal compound, but it is very easy to *cause damage during replacement*.

Comment: What can casse damage, replacing thermal compound? Why? Can you please elaborate?